# how to replace <br/> with <p> elements in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<page>
  <p>
    Republic of India (Bhārat Gaṇarājya),[c] is a country in South Asia.
    <br/>It is the seventh-largest country by geographical area.
    <br/> the second-most populous country with over 1.2 billion people, and the most populous democracy in the world.
  </p>
</page>
```

I need to replace `<br>`with`<p>` element.

```
<p>Republic of India (Bhārat Gaṇarājya),[c] is a country in South Asia.</p>
    <p>It is the seventh-largest country by geographical area.</p>
    <p>the second-most populous country with over 1.2 billion people, and the most populous democracy in the world.</p>
```

how to do this ?

Comment: Depending on your requirements there are a myriad ways of doing this. Please be more specific.

Comment: just that output is enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is use a key to match all child elements of the **p** elements, grouping them by the most preceding **br** elements (or by the parent **p** element if no preceding **br** element).

```
 <xsl:key 
    name="bits" 
    match="p/node()[not(self::br)]" 
   use="generate-id((..|preceding-sibling::br[1])[last()])"/>
```

Then, you can match all **br** elements within the **p** and output the following non-br elements within the key

```
<p>
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('bits', generate-id())"/>
<p>
```

You would also have a case for the first lot of child elements that do not have a preceding **br** element.

Here is the full xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="bits" match="p/node()[not(self::br)]" use="generate-id((..|preceding-sibling::br[1])[last()])"/>

   <xsl:template match="p">
      <p>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="key('bits', generate-id())"/>
      </p>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="br"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="p/br">
      <p>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="key('bits', generate-id())"/>
      </p>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="page">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<p>       
   Republic of India (Bhārat Gaṇarājya),[c] is a country in South Asia.       
</p>
<p>
   It is the seventh-largest country by geographical area.       
</p>
<p>
   the second-most populous country with over 1.2 billion people, and the most populous democracy in the world.       
</p>
```

This should also handle nested **p** elements, as well as retaining other HTML other than **p** and** within the text.